# How to change the Quick Favorites key in Blender 2.80 Beta?

Tags: customization, quick-favorites

Today I started using a newer version of Blender 2.80 and they changed the quick favorites key binding from <kbd>q</kbd> to <kbd>^</kbd>. While this in itself is okay, I'd still like to change that back.

But I can not find the key binding option for Quick Favorites in the keymaper in the preferences. Is this hard coded? Is this a bug? 
How can I change that back?

Thanks already!

Comment: A friend found it:
You can find it in the keymapping under Window / Call Menu. The name is SCREEN_MT_user_menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Menu: *Edit* -> *Preferences* -> *Keymap* choose *Window* - there's *Quick Favorites*.

[image]

You can always use search to find what you need.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You simply click on the option in the menu with the right button and then on Add to Quick Favourites.[image]