# Re-order quick favorites in blender

Tags: shortcut, customization, quick-favorites

How can I re-order my quick favorites (accessed by pressing the <kbd>**Q**</kbd> key) in Blender 2.83?

I looked at [How to change the Quick Favorites key in Blender 2.80 Beta?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/137841/how-to-change-the-quick-favorites-key-in-blender-2-80-beta)

But I don't have them bound to any keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly it doesn't seem to be possible. You can remove and add items to the quick favorites to somewhat reorder them but that seems to be the most you can do for now.

Comment: WTH Why can’t they be reordered? That is a serious limitation. :(

Comment: @DolphinDream There is an addon called SIMPLE TABS that allows you to reorder them. It's a god send. NVM I thought this was about tabs not quick favorites